# Q: coshx is 1 - 1

Tags: calculus

$$\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$$

If $f(x)=\cosh x$
how can I prove that $f(x)$ is $1-1$ on $[0,\infty)$ and find $f^{-1}(x)$ ?
Because when I try to do $f(x)=y$ I have two $x$...

Comment: It's one-to-one on $[0,\infty)$, but not on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: How would you solve for $z$ in the equation $z+\frac{1}{z}=2y$? If you knew that $z\geq 1$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yeah right, I edited but I still cant find the $f^{-1}(x)$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\cosh(x)=\sinh(x)>0\ \forall\ x\in[0,\infty)$$

So the function is monotonically increasing over the interval $[0,\infty)$.  Since $\cosh$ is continuous and monotone over the interval, it is bijective, hence, one to one.